# How to make an executable require root password?

Tags: sudo, scripts

How do you make an executable file (a shell script not of my own creation), when be accessed, pop up a little window requesting the password (as of now it is set to all executable, owner read and right, group and others only read.)

Comment: Call gksu or kdesudo, which show the dialog and run the program as root. From a script, call those utilities around the part that requires root permission.

Comment: What kind of executable file? Are you programming now in C++ for example and trying to find a way to integrate with PolicyKit for example? Or do you mean in scripting like `gksudo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than touching the current shell script, you can make a *wrapper* to call it with more permissions.

Save the script from below, make it executable (e.g. `chmod +x mysudowrapper.sh`), and use it like this:

```
./mysudowrapper.sh /path/to/originalscript.sh
```

Then make the `originalscript.sh` only runnable by `root`:

```
chown root:root /path/to/originalscript.sh
chmod go-x /path/to/originalscript.sh
```

Test it:

```
/path/to/originalscript.sh
bash: /path/to/originalscript.sh: Permission denied
```

Via wrapper script as above should work. From here you should be all set.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wrapper to run commands with sudo. Uses gksudo in a GUI environment, falls back on 
# plain sudo in non-GUI environment.
# Info: http://askubuntu.com/a/244690/88802
# Author(s): Gert van Dijk
# Disclaimer: No warranties whatsoever. I'm not responsible for any damage here.
# Purpose of this script is to *demonstrate* a wrapper to run other commands.

GKSUDO=/usr/bin/gksudo
SUDO=/usr/bin/sudo
gui_sudo () { # Run command with a GUI-capable sudo-wrapper
    $GKSUDO -- $SUDO "$@"
}

plain_sudo () { # Run command with the plain sudo wrapper
    $SUDO "$@"
}

has_gui () { # Checks for whether GUI is available via the $DISPLAY environment
    if [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]; then return 0; else return 1; fi
}

has_args () { # Checks for valid amount of arguments
    if [ "$1" != "" ]; then return 0; else return 1; fi
}

print_usage () { # Prints usage
    echo "Usage: $0 <command> [args]"
}

if has_args $@; then
    if has_gui; then gui_sudo $@; else plain_sudo $@; fi
else
    print_usage; exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I seem to be getting this error (which I no not how tho fix since it has been a bit since I have played with bash.)

`chris@Chris-Laptop-Ubuntu:~$ ~/bin/Sudoer /usr/bin/minecraft
/home/chris/bin/Sudoer: line 31: syntax error: unexpected end of file
`

(Oh yes, and if you are wondering why I am doing this to minecraft, it is because I like it when people have to ask me to go on minecraft. POWER)

Comment: @PyRulez Seems like you're right :) I was trying too hard to get it more compact, but made a mistake. Now copy the script again.

Comment: It seems (and this worked by the way) that I had to rename the original script to something new, and then make another script with the same name which runs `./mysudowrapper.sh /path/to/originalscript_old.sh`

Comment: Oh yes, and when I do that it works like a charm (an evil charm that allows me to control others, mu ha ha.) Thank you.